# How to get only number in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace

I have a two different different numbers, each with a dollar sign. I want to get the two numbers separately.

**JavaScript:**

```js
function price_range(id){
     //var str = $('#'+id).val();
     var str = '$75 - $300';
     var removeDollar = str.replace(/\$/,'');
     alert(removeDollar);
}
```

```html
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="price_range('amount')">Click Here</a>
```

The above code only replaces the first dollar sign, but I have two dollar signs with number. How can I get `75` and `300` separately?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can just get all the numbers from the string, like this

```
console.log('$75 - $300'.match(/(\d+)/g));
# [ '75', '300' ]
```

**Note:** This simple RegEx will match and get all the numbers, even if there are more than 2 numbers in the string. But for this simple task, you don't need a complicate RegEx.

If you want to fix your program, you can do it like this

```
console.log('$75 - $300'.replace(/\$/g, '').split(/\s*-\s*/));
# [ '75', '300' ]
```

`replace(/\$/g, '')` will replace `$` symbol from the string and then you can split the string based on `\s*-\s*`, which means zero or more white space characters, followed by `-`, and followed by zero or more white space characters.

Comment: Coooooooooooooool...       Thanks.. :)

Answer (score 1):

You could extend the regular expression in the `.replace()` function to have a global flag `g`:

```
str.replace(/\$/g,'');
```

The whole script would work like this, but will be specific to removing the $ sign.

```js
function price_range(id){
     //var str = $('#'+id).val();
     var str = '$75 - $300';
     var removeDollar = str.replace(/\$/g,'');
     alert(removeDollar);
}
```

```html
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="price_range('amount')">Click Here</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

An option would be to extract numbers with a regular expression like this:

```
var str = '$70 - $300 some other 500%';
var arrOfStrings = str.match(/\d+/gi);
// arrOfStrings = ['70', '300', '500']
var arrOfNrs = arrOfStrings.map(function (e) {
    return parseInt(e);
});  // map not supported by all browsers. you can use the _.map from underscorejs.org
// arrOfNrs = [70, 300, 500]
```

Comment: Map takes a function as a parameter: var arrOfNrs = arrOfStrings.map(parseInt);

Comment: Doesn't work, because `parseInt` takes `radix` as the second argument, and `map` would assign the index of the array element as the `radix` which would yield invalid results. So basically it would give the correct result for the first element (idx: 0) and the 11th (idx: 10)

Comment: Oh I see. I don't use JavaScript that much. Disregard my comment then.